# Kotlin Assign Delegate After Variable Declaration

Tags: android, kotlin

So, basically I have a class:

```
class App : Application() {

    lateinit var prefs: SharedPreferences

}
```

Now, I want to add a delegated property:

```
var isInitialized: Boolean by prefs.boolean()
```

The problem is that this, **isInitialized** property must be initialized lazily since I'm using Android Dagger2 framework, which performs injection after **App** creation (during calling **onCreate()** method):

```
class App : Application() {

    lateinit var prefs: SharedPreferences

    var isInitialized: Boolean = false

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        // how can I assign a delegate to isInitialized?

    }

}
```

I would like it to be done either via:

- lazy initialization during declaration (which is delegate in delegate - wondering whether this possible?)
- lazy initialization during assignment

Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do it with an indirection:

```
class DoubleDelegate<R, T>(var realDelegate: ReadWriteProperty<R, T> = /* some default */) : ReadWriteProperty<R, T> by realDelegate
```

then

```
val isInitializedDelegate = DoubleDelegate<App, Boolean>()

var isInitialized: Boolean by isInitializedDelegate 

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    isInitializedDelegate.realDelegate = prefs.boolean()
}
```

Somehow I don't think this is actually a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Lazy**

From the document [Lazy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-lazy/) Gets the lazily initialized value of the current Lazy instance. Once the value was initialized it must not change during the rest of lifetime of this Lazy instance.

Application class

```
val prefs: Prefs by lazy {
 App.prefs!!
 }

 class App : Application() {
 companion object {
 var prefs: Prefs? = null
 }

override fun onCreate() {
prefs = Prefs(applicationContext)
super.onCreate()
}
}
```

your data model class should be like this

```
class Prefs (context: Context) {
val PREFS_FILENAME = "com.teamtreehouse.colorsarefun.prefs"
val IsInitialized = "isInitialized"
val prefs: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILENAME, 0);
var initialized: Boolean
get() = prefs. getBoolean(IsInitialized, false)
set(value) = prefs.edit(). putBoolean(IsInitialized, value).apply()
}
```

then use Activity or fragment

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

val initialized = prefs.initialized //getvalue
selectvalue(false)// set value

}

  private fun selectvalue(value: Boolean) {
   prefs.initialized = value
  }
}
```

more details refer this example [SharedPreferences Easy with Kotlin](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/making-sharedpreferences-easy-with-kotlin)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah, I found something similar. So, there is no way to make it work without creating additional model? Meaning I can't have, say, 2 boolean properties in different activities without having them also in the model.